# Angularjs fails http get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying some angularjs tutorials and dont know why the dropdown does not populate.

I get an error in angular.js file

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function. 
if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', newUrl,
                                    oldUrl).defaultPrevented) {
```

below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.js" />
</head>
<body ng-app = "subtitle" ng-controller="loginController">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> 
<select ng-model="collections" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in languages">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>

(function(){

var app = angular.module('subtitle',[]);

app.controller('loginController', ['$http','$scope',function($scope,$http) {
$scope.collections = null;
$scope.languages = [];

$http.get('http://lapi.cd.com/masterdata?type=languages').success(function(data) {
$scope.languages = data;
});
}]);

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have switched the order of the variables in the controller:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$http','$scope',function($scope,$http)
```

Switch to:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope)
```

Comment: Exactly, what I failed to detect.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!!! [plnker](http://embed.plnkr.co/0uQbXzoy4JvciZzz3Pp5/preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('subtitle', []);
    app.controller('loginController', ['$http', '$scope',
      function($http,$scope) {
        $scope.collections = null;
        $scope.languages = [];

        $http.get('http://lapi.cd.com/masterdata?type=languages').success(function(data) {
          $scope.languages = data;
        });
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="subtitle" ng-controller="loginController">
  <select ng-model="collections" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in languages">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the order of injections you make is not right. It must be fixed, as shown below:

app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http' , function($scope, $http) { ... }]);

('ctrlName', ['A', 'B', function(A, B) ...